# What is a good way to make a calculation based on the state of a series of pairs of radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

I have a table containing an unknown number of rows, each with two radio buttons with names weight[i] and winner[i], and with ids such as weight11, weight12, weight21, weight22, winner11, winner12, etc...

I'm trying to make a loop that calculates the sum of the product of the values of all of these radio buttons.

I'm having trouble writing the correct query in order to get the value of the radio buttons when the name of the radio buttons contains a variable.

Can you see what the correct query would be, or can you see a different solution for this?

I've tried making a loop using php instead, but I have trouble getting the value of the number of rows in php, as that can change dynamically without any reloading of the table.

Table:

```
<table class="comparisontable" id="ComparisonTable">
    <col width=15%>
    <col width=15%>
    <col width=20%>
    <col width=5%>
    <col width=20%>
    <col width=25%>
    <tr>
        <th class="headingleft">Criteria</th>
        <th class="headingcenter">Criteria weight</th>
        <th class="headingcenter"><p><p><input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'" class="productchoice" type="text" id="productA" name="productA" value = "<?php echo $array[0]["ProductA"];?>"></p><p id=prodscoreA>Score: </p></th> 
        <th class="headingcenter">
        <th class="headingcenter"><p><p><input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'" class="productchoice" type="text" id="productB" name="productB" value = "<?php echo $array[0]["ProductB"];?>"></p><p id=prodscoreB>Score: </p></th>
        <th class="headingleft">Comment</th>
    </tr>


<!-- Criteria rows creation and loading, in a loop: -->
    <?php
        $i = 1; 
        while($array[$i-1]["FormNumber"]) {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td class="criteria"><input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'" class="criteriainput" type="text" id="criteria<?php echo "$i";?>" name="criteria[<?php echo "$i";?>]" value="<?php echo $array[$i-1]["Criteria"];?>"></td>
        <td class="weight">
            <li class="star-weight">
                <input type="radio" onclick="CalculateScores()" name="weight[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="weight<?php echo "$i";?>3" value="3" <?= $array[$i-1]["Weight"] == "3" ? 'checked' : '' ?> /><label for="weight<?php echo "$i";?>3"></label>
                <input type="radio" onclick="CalculateScores()" name="weight[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="weight<?php echo "$i";?>2" value="2" <?= $array[$i-1]["Weight"] == "2" ? 'checked' : '' ?> /><label for="weight<?php echo "$i";?>2"></label>
                <input type="radio" onclick="CalculateScores()" name="weight[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="weight<?php echo "$i";?>1" value="1" <?= $array[$i-1]["Weight"] == "1" ? 'checked' : '' ?> /><label for="weight<?php echo "$i";?>1"></label>
            </li>
        </td>
        <td class="winner">
            <input type="radio" onclick="CalculateScores()" name="winner[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="winner<?php echo "$i";?>10000" value="10000" <?= $array[$i-1]["Winner"] == "10000" ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Winner</input><br>
            <textarea class="commentinput" name="commentA[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="commentA<?php echo "$i";?>" cols="1" rows="3"><?php echo $array[$i-1]["CommentA"];?></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" onclick="CalculateScores()" name="winner[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="winner<?php echo "$i";?>100" value="100" <?= $array[$i-1]["Winner"] == "100" ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Tie</input><br>
            <input class="hidden" type="radio" name="winner<?php echo "$i";?>" id="winner<?php echo "$i";?>0" value="0" <?= $array[$i-1]["Winner"] == NULL ? 'checked' : '' ?>><br>
        </td>
        <td class="winner">
            <input type="radio" onclick="CalculateScores()" name="winner[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="winner<?php echo "$i";?>1" value="1" <?= $array[$i-1]["Winner"] == "1" ? 'checked' : '' ?>> Winner</input><br>
            <textarea class="commentinput" name="commentB[<?php echo "$i";?>]" id="commentB<?php echo "$i";?>" cols="1" rows="3"><?php echo $array[$i-1]["CommentB"];?></textarea>
        </td>
        <td class="comment">
            <textarea class="commentinput" name="comment[<?php echo "$i" ;?>]" id="comment<?php echo "$i" ;?>" cols="1" rows="4"><?php echo $array[$i-1]["Comment"];?></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
            $i++;
        }
    ?>

</table>
```

Javascript function:

```
function CalculateScores() {
    // Sum of product of weights and winners:
    var SumProd = 0;
    var l = 1;
    var rows = document.getElementById("ComparisonTable").rows.length;
    while(l < rows) {
        SumProd += document.querySelector('input[name="weight[" + l + "]"]:checked').value*document.querySelector('input[name="winner[" + l + "]"]:checked').value;
        l++;
    }
```

I'm hoping to get SumProd to be equal to the sum of the products of the checked weight[l] and winner[l] radio buttons.

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML and the desired output from it?

Comment: *ids such as weight 11, weight 12, weight 21, weight 22* << `id`s can't contain spaces.

Comment: And, you are using "smart quotes" instead of "straight quotes" in your code, which will cause errors.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "weight11, weight12, ..." - darn autocorrect! :)

Comment: I fixed the smart quotes (unfortunately that wasn't enough to fix the issue), and added the HTML code to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments inline but don't forget that you should be using unique `name` attribute values for each set of radio buttons and you need to use straight-quotes, and not smart quotes.

```js
// Get all the rows into an array:
let rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr"));

let sum = 0;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Loop over the array
  rows.forEach(function(row){
    // Get the selected radio button
    let checkedButton = row.querySelector(":checked");
    
    // If a selection was made, add the value (converted to a number) of the checked radio button to the sum
    if(checkedButton !== null){
      sum += +checkedButton.value;
    }
  });

  console.log(sum);  // Output result
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Choice 1:<input type="radio" value="5" name="g1"> Choice 2:<input type="radio" value="10" name="g1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Choice 1:<input type="radio" value="15" name="g2"> Choice 2:<input type="radio" value="20" name="g2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Choice 1:<input type="radio" value="25" name="g3"> Choice 2:<input type="radio" value="30" name="g3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Choice 1:<input type="radio" value="35" name="g4"> Choice 2:<input type="radio" value="40" name="g4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Choice 1:<input type="radio" value="45" name="g5"> Choice 2:<input type="radio" value="50" name="g5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Get Sum</button>
```

UPDATE:

For your scenario, inside the loop, you would just need to get the checked weight and the checked winner radio button values, multiply them and then add the result to the final sum:

```
  // Loop over the array
  rows.forEach(function(row){
    // Get the selected radio buttons
    let weight = row.querySelector("[name^='weight']:checked");
    let winner = row.querySelector("[name^='winner']:checked");

    // If a selection was made, multiply the values (converted to a number) 
    // of the checked radio buttons and add to the sum
    if(weight && winner){
      sum += (+weight.value * +winner.value);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to adapt that to my form and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Thanks, it works great for calculating the sum of the values of one radio button! Do you however have a suggestion for calculating the sum of the product of the values of two radio buttons?

Comment: @Michael You would simply change the math in the one line. But, radio buttons imply a single choice, this doesn't seem to make sense to multiply the values of both the checked and the unchecked radio button.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear: what I meant is that I want to multiply the value of the checked weight[i] radio buttons with the checked winner[i] radio buttons - I'm unsure how to do this when using "rows.forEach(function(row){" - can I somehow apply that function to both my weight and my winner radio buttons?